# Ignoring <tr> tag with nth-child css

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a pretty complex situation here so I am going to try my best to explain.

I have this table with `<tr>` and `<td>` html tags and I want every user displayed to be sorted with 2 different css `background-color`.

The problem is that I have another `<tr>` tag where the date is displayed for every user, so when trying to use these elements with `tr:nth-child(even)` and `tr:nth-child(odd)` it will not work.

So how should I do to make this work? I tried with selecting with different intervalls as you can see here, with no result.

Note: The first user should always start with white `background-color`.

```
#tblRegister tr:nth-child(2n-4) {
    background-color: #eee;
}

#tblRegister tr:nth-child(3n-1) {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Here is an image to further explain how it should be:

[image]

Comment: Please show us HTML code of table too.

Comment: if you will post a working example it will be a lot helpfull to answer

Comment: @Autista_z Trust me the HTML code is complex with alot of ASP.NET server-side functions, it will only confuse the readers.

Comment: If you can change the HTML structure, i would suggest to create multiple tables and apply the nth-child style to the "son" tables. Otherwise i cannot think of a solution

Comment: @Malphai So just simplyfied version, basic structure with the dates TR, so we see what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like i said previously in my comment, i would change my html structure to apply the nth-child rule like so:

## HTML

```
<table>
  <tr class="big_row">
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="son_table_cnt">
    <td>
      <table class="son_table">
          <tr class="normal_row">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="normal_row">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="normal_row">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="normal_row">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

## CSS

```
tr.normal_row:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}

tr.normal_row:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

I know that nested tables are a pain, but i cannot think of another solution. Maybe someone else can come up with a better one without changing the structure

You can find a working example here https://jsfiddle.net/qzL7kgev/1/ (css is a bit messy cause i layed it down quickly, but i hope you get the point)

Answer (score -1):

Try to like this

```
#tblRegister tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: #eee;
}

#tblRegister tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: This does not work, the first row will be gray because of date <tr>!